# How do I prevent a user from copying files from a remote Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, permissions, filesystem

Is there any setting scripts or ideas in remote server to achieve that goal? The user is the computer user, such as administrator or guest, rather than Web application user or others.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  To answer your question, we need you need to be more specific.  For example, how are people accessing this server?  What have you tried so far? Users generally don't have write access to files outside their own home directory and certain parts of the filesystem are blocked from reading also.  What files or folders are you trying to restrict access to?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @tudor. The user accesses the remote server in his own local machine through a putty client using the account of the server machine. Is that description clear enough?

Comment: Putty as in SSH?  And what is the "account of the server machine".  Is it an account that is shared or a user account for that particular user on that particular server?  You may want to read something like http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/file-permissions-reference

Comment: Yes, it is a user account for that particular user on that particular server. The link is quit helpful, thanks. But i still have a blurring concept of file permission. If the user does not have access to the file, does it mean that the user can not copy the file?

Comment: If the user does not not have *read* access to the file, they cannot read it.    If they are the owner of the file then the "user read" bit applies to them, but they may also have read access if "other read" permission is enabled on the file or if the file has "group read" permission and the group of the file matches a group they are in.  See `man groups`,  `man chmod`, and `man chown`.  I'd highly recommend taking a tutorial like this one: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions

Answer (score 0):

This is better covered by a Linux permissions tutorial, like [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions).

But, in a nutshell, and *presuming that the user has **not** been given sudo access or access to root in any way*, and also presuming that it is only **read** access we are concerned about (not write or execute):

To restrict access to **one particular file**, make sure that:

(1) The file is not "**r**ead" accessible by "**a**nyone" (shorthand for "**u**ser "**g**roup" and "**o**ther"):

```
$ chmod a-r <filename>
```

(2) The file is not owned by the user:

```
$ ls -o <filename>
----------  1 baduser   74609996 May 24 17:51  mysecret
$ chown <atrusteduser> <filename>
```

I'd highly recommend putting any users you're not sure of [in a jail shell](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/j/jailed-shell.htm) instead though, at the very least.

Also, don't forget the SysAdmin's security mantra: **You can never make a system completely secure.  You must always assume that your system is already infiltrated and attempt to limit the damage.  Backup backup 
 and verify your backup.**